# How to get data of select2 with POST method

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I need to return data of the select2 with POST method.
does anyone have any idea what can I do?
I tried this but did not even work.

```js
$("#action").select2({
  allowHtml: true,
  ajax: {
    type: "POST",
    url: URL,
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      Authorization: "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem("api_token")
    },
    dataType: "json",
    data: function(term, page) {
      console.log(term);
      return {
        string: term
      };
    },
    processResults: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      return {
        results: data.map(item => {
          return {
            text: item.title,
            id: item.id
          };
        })
      };
    }
  },
  allowClear: !0
});
```

```html
<input class="form-control" id="action">
```

The code does not even show the log.

Comment: To debug AJAX requests, use the network tab of devtools. You'll see the request in there, along with it's statusCode and responseText. They should give you enough information to begin debugging

Comment: It does not even call the ajax method in the network  @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan No, nothing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was I added input instead of select tag
I solve the issue like this

```js
$("#action").select2({
  allowHtml: true,
  ajax: {
    type: "POST",
    url: URL,
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      Authorization: "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem("api_token")
    },
    dataType: "json",
    data: function(term, page) {
      console.log(term);
      return {
        string: term
      };
    },
    processResults: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      return {
        results: data.map(item => {
          return {
            text: item.title,
            id: item.id
          };
        })
      };
    }
  },
  allowClear: !0
});
```

```html
<select class="form-control" id="action"></select>
```